# How to flatten JavaPairDStream<string,ArrayList<string>> into JavaDStream<string> in java spark streaming

Tags: java, arraylist, apache-spark, spark-streaming

spark-streaming : I have a intermediate result as JavaPairDStream and want to transform into JavaDStream where output should be having the flatten Arraylist values.

```
 input example : [1,{2,3,4},6,{x,y,z}]

output required : 2,3,4,x,y,z
```

flatten the records.

Comment: So you want to get rid of the 1 and 6 in the input?

Comment: yes... i want to flatten the arraylist elements in spark streaming using java

Comment: Flattening for the example input you gave would be 1,2,3,4,6,x,y,z... That is why I asked

Answer (score 0):

Python code(please translate to java APIs):

```
data = [(1,[2,3,4]),(6,['x','y','z'])]
distData = sc.parallelize(data)
distData.map(lambda m: m[1]).flatMap(lambda m:m).collect()
=================output===============
[2, 3, 4, 'x', 'y', 'z']
```